# scaling of rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, scalability

what scaling options can we use if rabbitMQ metrices reaches a threshold?I have a VM on which RabbitMQ is running. If the queue length>90% of total queue length, can we increase the instance count by 1 and a with a separate queue such that they are to be processed on a priority basis?

In short what scaling options do we have based on different parameters for RabbitMQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [RabbitMQ Sharding Plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding)

From their README:

> **RabbitMQ Sharding Plugin**
>
> This plugin introduces the concept of sharded queues for RabbitMQ.
>   Sharding is performed by exchanges, that is, messages will be
>   partitioned across "shard" queues by one exchange that we should
>   define as sharded. The machinery used behind the scenes implies
>   defining an exchange that will partition, or shard messages across
>   queues. The partitioning will be done automatically for you, i.e: once
>   you define an exchange as sharded, then the supporting queues will be
>   automatically created on every cluster node and messages will be
>   sharded across them.
>
> **Auto-scaling**
>
> One interesting property of this plugin, is that if you add more nodes
>   to your RabbitMQ cluster, then the plugin will automatically create
>   more shards in the new node. Say you had a shard with 4 queues in node
>   a and node b just joined the cluster. The plugin will automatically
>   create 4 queues in node b and join them to the shard partition.
>   Already delivered messages will not be rebalanced, but newly arriving
>   messages will be partitioned to the new queues.